# What advantages are there to the Codex Scanner?

Tags: warframe

On Warframe, there is an item called the Codex Scanner, which allows you to scan enemies to get an entry on them. Besides earning data on them, are there any other advantages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use it you get a small amount of XP, the amount of xp is larger if it is a stealth scan and will count as 2 scans.

Since the Codex Scanner shows boxes and can see them through walls it can be used to spot hidden rooms with boxes.

It is also very handy for spotting enemies through walls if you are trying to do stealth missions.

Before the release of the Codex scanner the developers said on a live stream that maxing data on a target would give a bonus towards the target like extra crit, but at this time there is no indication that this feature has been added.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly visual advantage added with the release of Syndicate Syndanas -- When you scan an enemy or when Helios scans an enemy, if you have the Synoid Syndana (for Cephalon Suda) it will glow brighter as a result.

[Source](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Synoid_Syandana)